# Row stays highlighted

Tags: javascript, html

i am having trouble with this script.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }, false);
});
```

It highlights the row but if i click on another row then both rows are highlighted. i need a script that highlights one row at a time and not all of them.
What did i forget, if something is not clear let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the style for all `'tr'` before applying the style on the selected one. So your updated code would look like:

```
const items = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
[].forEach.call(items, function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
       [].forEach.call(items, function(ele) {
          ele.style.backgroundColor = ''; // initial value
       });
       item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
   }, false);
});
```

Comment: I have an error saying that it is " , or ) expected

Comment: <script>
    const items = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    [].forEach.call(items, function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            [].forEach.call(items, function(ele) {
                ele.style.backgroundColor = ''; // initial value
            }
            item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }, false);
    });
</script>

Comment: Yeah I missed one parentheses `)` after the inner for each loop. I updated it Thanks

Comment: Thanks :D  life saver